# root full when i copy the data to AWS s3 bucket

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, centos6, system-administration

why my centos directory / is full when i copy the data to AWS s3 bucket. file size is around 6 gb. it seems file is also copied to /tmp folder. & my server / is having 7 gb...please help me to sort out how can i move my files to s3 bucket without using /tmp folder.

Comment: how are you copying it? aws-cli's `s3 cp` method? through a SDK?

Comment: i am using cp command & i have mounted the bucket with below command..#/usr/bin/s3fs kaar-ma.com -o nonempty -o allow_other /buckettc02 -ouse_cache=/tmp. i guess i should not use the cache/tmp entry while mounting

Comment: can any one help me to out of this problem ?

Comment: Sid you try mounting without the cache?